# German film where two men hold a couple hostage

Tags: identify-this-movie

In 2000s (it aired in America definitely before 2009, when I moved abroad) I was watching a very well made movie on cable.  I was in the United States, but it was a German movie, so it 'made it over here.'

To the best of my memory, it takes place in a rural / forested setting, and two men are tormenting a married couple, tying them up, etc.

There is at least one moment of 'fourth wall' where the couple escapes and one of the men quickly says - hold on - and rewinds the scene and catches them.

The cinematography was clean and bright and there were a lot of daytime scenes.  It wasn't artsy-weird, but it was independent-foreign thriller.  I'm sorry I can't elaborate; due to schedule I only saw the bulk of the 'middle' of the movie.  I'd love to watch the whole thing.

EDIT: Just checked the guidelines, I'll try to add more information (below).

Descriptions of any characters or locations - *Caucasion, German, mid-20s in a Forest area in summer-ish time; the abusers a little bit like college-style punks*

Whether it was animated or not - *Not animated*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are clearly referring to Michael Haneke's [*Funny Games*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119167/), an Austrian film from 1997 which features not only the general setting of a family being help captive by two young men, but has exactly your described [fourth wall scene with the rewind](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/26787/49). As to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funny_Games_(1997_film)):

> When Anna successfully shoots Peter, as a possible start to a heroic escape for the family, Paul uses a remote control to rewind the film itself and prevent her action.

There is, however, even a [US remake](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0808279/) from 2007 by the same director that you might have seen too.

Comment: Thanks, I've upvoted and will accept.  From the movie stills, it is definitely correct. As it's my first identify-this-movie, any feedback on improving my question would be great.

Comment: @Mikey For a first time ID question it is comparatively quite good. It can be seen that you put effort into formulating your question.

Comment: @Mikey I'd advise to do some research yourself first: https://www.google.com/search?q=german+movie+tormenting+couple+fourth+wall shows several times "Funny Games" as the result.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - Thanks!  I started with 'German film murderers couple' and quickly realized SE would be a better go-to as it allows a more elaborate question.  I'll keep in mind for any future ID questions to be more specific in google first; thanks for the help.